# How to Make Header Menu Vertically Aligned & Icon aligned to the left

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a header for a webpage that has a horizontal menu tab (composed of links to other html files), but I find it hard to align the icon on the same horizontal row as the menu tab while keeping the icon and tabs aligned differently (icon to the left, tabs to the right). When I move the icon out of the same group as the links and use css to make them aligned differently, the result is the two (icon and tabs) being in separate rows. I even tried using the align attribute directly to the image tag but it made everything align to the left as well.

So here is my code so far, using a random logo image.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    <title>[Website-Name] | Home</title>
</head>
<style type="text/css">
    img {
        text-align: left;
    }
    ul {
        text-align: right;
        padding: 0px;
        margin: 0px
    }
    a{
        color: white; 
        text-decoration: none; /* remove link underline*/
        font-size: 20px;
    }
    div/*MENU CSS*/ {
        background: black;
    }

    a:hover /* Change color mouse hover */,
    a:active {
        color: orange;
    }

    li { /*Space between tabs */
        display: inline;
        padding: 0px 25px 0px 25px; /* distance between menu tabs*/
            vertical-align: middle;
    }


</style>
<body>
    <nav>
    <div>
    <img src="icon.jpg">    
        <ul>
            <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="drawing.html">Drawing</a></li>
            <li><a href="music.html">Music</a></li>
            <li><a href="handcrafted.html">Handcrafted</a></li>
            <li><a href="literature.html">Literature</a></li>
            <li><a href="search.html">Search</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    </nav>
</body>
</html>
```

So here is an image comparing what I would like the code to do and what the code (above) is actually doing:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/hTGob.jpg

And here is the icon.jpg used in the code above:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/qW4UU.jpg

Thanks in advance, and please ask if there is something you would like me to clarify on!

Comment: you give vertical align middle to the img

Comment: When I add vertical align to the image in css, @MarkoMackic, it doesn't do anything and also I'm trying to vertically align the tabs, not the image.

Comment: Vertical align doesn't seem to work for the ul or the li either, strange.

Comment: If you'd make a fiddle I might take a look

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
li { /*Space between tabs */
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0px 25px 0px 25px; /* distance between menu tabs*/
    vertical-align: central;
    line-height:100%;
    height:100%;
}
a{
    display: inline-block;
    line-height:100px;
    height:100%;
}
div/*MENU CSS*/ {
    background: black;
    height:100px;
}
img {
    text-align: left;
    height:100px;
}
ul {
    text-align: right;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    float:right;
    height:100%;
}
```

Replace the following css elements, this assumes the image height is 100px so change all occurrences of that to the actual height of your image

Comment: Adding these properties simply hide the tabs and show only the icon.

Comment: Sorry, I had made an assumption, I just tested and I'll edit my answer

Comment: Is the height of the image fixed? if that's the case I have an answer

Comment: Well, I can make it fixed. I tried using the properties you edited and it did fix the row problem. The tabs are aligned to the top now, not the middle. How do I fix that problem?

Comment: Here's a link to my jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/5azrzhjx/ . This assumes the height of the image is 100px so change any occurrences of that to the height of your image. Also, for testing purposes, I've decreased the padding of the "li" elements to 5 instead of 25 due to the small screen available in the tester, so just change that back for your project.

Answer (score 0):

You can use flexbox with the following settings for your DIV which is inside `nav`:

(note: i reduced the padding so all menu items would fit into the snippet widow next to each other)

```
nav>div {
  height: 100px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```css
nav>div {
  height: 100px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

img {
  text-align: left;
}

ul {
  text-align: right;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px
}

a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  /* remove link underline*/
  font-size: 20px;
}

div
/*MENU CSS*/

{
  background: black;
}

a:hover
/* Change color mouse hover */

,
a:active {
  color: orange;
}

li {
  /*Space between tabs */
  display: inline;
  padding: 0px 10px 0px 10px;
  /* distance between menu tabs*/
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <div>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/50x40/fa0">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="drawing.html">Drawing</a></li>
      <li><a href="music.html">Music</a></li>
      <li><a href="handcrafted.html">Handcrafted</a></li>
      <li><a href="literature.html">Literature</a></li>
      <li><a href="search.html">Search</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Interesting. Can you explain what the flex does? I don't think I quite understand what makes this work.

Comment: First of all it places the direct child elements in its container along an axis (horizontally or vertically). Other settings allow to influence the distribution of the child elements (at the start, end, centered, evenly spread), automatic shrinking or growing of the children, and the alignment along the cross-axis (like the vertical centering in my snippet ). It's really too much stuff for such a short answer, but it's quite flexible - just google "flexbox", there are plenty of tutorials and articles. The only disadvantage is that it's not compatible to some older browsers.